# How to sense the two magnet attracting each other

Tags: magnetometer

I have a cube that has four side sticked with magnet sheet and I have other boxes like this and I want to know how could I sense each time a cube is connected to to another and other and other 
I have read about magnetometer but I am not sure if it works with this situation

Comment: An easy way is to use your eyes so please explain why a human sense could not or cannot solve this problem?

Comment: Because I need to actuate a motor after this sense

Comment: Your question is vague. Post a picture of your setup. What are the cubes made of? How much room have we got? Are they arranged with N or S poles alternating on each side? Are the magnets conductive? Where is the motor? How will the signal get to the motor controller? What voltages can we work with? Much information missing.

Comment: So, use your senses then activate a motor switch. Why cannot this be a good way. Please explain why you want something different and note that this site is not telepathy.com

Comment: @Transistor I do not have the picture since it is just a prototype in mind, I did not buy magnets yet and I want to build this, motor is inside the cube, and I what to control this with arduino , generally I want to have blocks as modules to connect and when they connects motors start to work

Comment: But the first sentence of your question says, "I have a cube ... and other boxes like this". I think I might give up on this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your setup correctly, then yes, it should be possible to detect this with a magnetometer. If you stick two magnets together, they behave (in the first approximation) as one larger magnet<sup>[1](https://www.kjmagnetics.com/FAQ.asp#stack)</sup>, so the field should increase. For larger flat magnet and near its center, it should almost double, at least theoretically. You can test it in [this simulator](https://www.kjmagnetics.com/fieldcalculator.asp) for example.

[image: simulated field produced by the website linked above]

But in practice there is typically lot of unwanted and unexpected effects when doing any measurement, so the best is to try it experimentally in your particular setup. Get some magnetometer, which 
has enough range for field intensity close to the surface of you magnetic sheets, attach it to the middle of one sheet (with some small non-magnetic material spacer maybe), measure the field, put other sheet in place and measure again. You should, hopefully, see significant and reproducible change in the measured value.

I think this question is quite interesting and it would be great if you can share your findings in case you actually do such experiment.

Comment: Thanks martin of course I will test and let you know here